# Make: No rule to make target 'part2.d', needed by MahApp

Tags: linux, build, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
SOURCES = part1.cpp part2.cpp main.cpp
OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}
DEPS = ${SOURCES:.cpp=.d}
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -I -std=c++11
ExecutableName = Partsapp

BUILD_DIR = build/host

MahApp: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(DEPS) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJECTS)

build/host/%.d: ./%.cpp
    $(CXX) -MT$(@:.d=.o) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $^ > $@

-include build/host/$(DEPS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS) MahApp
```

Now, whenever I try to run it, I get the following error:

> No rule to make target 'part2.d', needed by 'MahApp'. Stop.

Now, the funny thing is that it does manage to create part1.d correctly from the pattern matching rule, however after that it just seizes to work, and I just can't figure out why!

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SOURCES = part1.cpp part2.cpp main.cpp
...
DEPS = ${SOURCES:.cpp=.d}
...
BUILD_DIR = build/host

MahApp: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(DEPS) ...
    ...
```

`DEPS` expands to `part1.d part2.d main.d`, so `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(DEPS)` expands to `build/host/part1.d part2.d main.d`, and Make is telling you it can't find `part2.d`.

The construction you want is:

```
BUILD_DIR = build/host
DEPS = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))
```

(There are other ways to do it.) And the way to examine your variables to see if they are what you think they are is like this:

```
$(info $(DEPS))
```